# Swift 3 Reworking Code Leaves Else Without An If(Parse Call) (edited)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I was tasked with consolidating the parse calls for this app into a single file. A lot of the calls had some sort of UI task attached to it. So the actual call is in the file while the UI tasks are still in their appropriate view controller. One that I'm having issue with is one that had an if let statement with an else that presented an alert, but the if let has to remain in the APIManager file. So, basically the `if let objects = objects as [PFObject]?` has to stay where it is, but the final else statement on the view controller was originally attached to it so now it has nothing to come before it.

For clarification the first and second code snippets are just the third snippet separated and then the query put into a different function in a separate file with a completion handler added to the function. When doing this the `if let objects = objects as [PFObject]?` section of the code must stay with the query, but the second else statement relies on it. Because if there are no objects then the error is to be displayed. I'm trying to figure out how to keep this functionality.

Below is the parse call and then the code that goes with it in the view controller. I'll also include the original method below this.

```
func viewNeedMetButton(completion: @escaping([PFObject?]) -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Need")
    query.whereKey("committed", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackground {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
            completion(objects)
        }
    }
}
```

Code that is on the view controller that works with the Parse Call.

```
@IBAction func markAsMet(_ sender: Any) {
    viewNeedMetButton { (objects) in
        if NeedStore.shared.currentNeed?.committed == true {
            for object in objects {
                NeedStore.shared.needObject?.setObject(true, forKey: "met")
                NeedStore.shared.needObject?.saveInBackground() { (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "You have marked this need as met!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                            (_)in
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToNeedsList", sender: self)
                        })
                        alert.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You cannot declare a need as met if it has not been committed to.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly the original code where everything was in the same function.

```
    @IBAction func markAsMet(_ sender: Any) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Need")
    query.whereKey("committed", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackground {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
            if NeedStore.shared.currentNeed?.committed == true {
                for object in objects {
                    NeedStore.shared.needObject?.setObject(true, forKey: "met")
                    NeedStore.shared.needObject?.saveInBackground() { (success, error) -> Void in
                        if success {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "You have marked this need as met!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                                (_)in
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToNeedsList", sender: self)
                            })
                            alert.addAction(OKAction)
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You cannot declare a need as met if it has not been committed to.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                    return
                })
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I greatly appreciate any help or advice on this :)

Comment: The second one makes no sense. An `if` cannot have two `else` clauses.

Comment: It doesn't. `if NeedStore.shared.currentNeed?.committed == true` takes the first else statement. `if let objects = objects as [PFObject]?` takes the second. The second is the one that doesn't have an if now because that if let has to be in file holding the parse calls.

Comment: Then your indentation is wrong. I do not have time to count curly braces and see whether it's that or whether you have curly braces wrong too. It is your job to post code that can be read.

Comment: You don't understand and are assuming it's my fault. The first two sections of code are both from the third piece. I had to take the query to Parse out of it and move it somewhere else. When I did that I had to add a completion handler to the function so it would run all of it's code before moving on. In doing so the `if let objects = objects as [PFObject]?` had to stay with the query. Now the 2nd else statement does not have an if attached to it whatsoever. It isn't curly braces. it isn't unreadable. It's something was there and had to be moved now I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I do indeed assume it's your fault. The second snippet purports to be a complete function `markAsMet`. If so, it would not compile, because it contains an `if` with two `else` clauses which is illegal. As for "you don't understand", please don't say that. Say "I did not make myself clear" and make yourself clear.

Comment: There are two if statements each handling their own else!

Comment: In the third one, yes. Not in the second one.

Comment: Exactly. The second has the if statement in the first piece of code and the help I need is on how to have that code there but have the if statement still work. The 3rd piece is the code before I had to move the query it compiled and works. The 1st and 2nd is where I moved the query. The `if let objects` has to stay with the call. The 2nd piece of code calls the query and then executes the code, but now the 2nd else doesn't have an if statement to go with it. I'm seeking guidance on how to fix this.

Comment: I sincerely apologize if I seemed bitter, but I thought you were basically calling me stupid that I couldn't see the code didn't have an if statement to go with it. I know it doesn't and that's what I'm having issues trying to fix because the second else statement is set to show an error if the array of objects comes back empty.

Comment: The first and 2nd snippet are basically the 3rd snippet pulled apart but with a completion handler added and since that if statement has to stay with the query that else now has nothing to go with it. I hope that makes sense I thought I was more clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

as other write in comments: an if with 2 else not works.

i don't know why you need to move the `if` to the other function. but here my solutions how to make it work as before

**hint:** if you like to extract a part to an other part, then you have to cut it always on the same level: in your case from `if NeedStore.shared.currentNeed?.committed == true {` until the `}` on the same level of the if (this is one block on one level: `if condition { ... } else { ... }`). and when you cut this off the the remaining part that of `1. Solution` cut of where not is the line `completion(objects)`

#### 1. Solution

you need to move the else part also to the other function `viewNeedMetButton` because it is called on an error.

```
func viewNeedMetButton(completion: @escaping([PFObject?]) -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Need")
    query.whereKey("committed", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackground {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
            completion(objects)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Code that is on the view controller that works with the Parse Call.

```
@IBAction func markAsMet(_ sender: Any) {
    viewNeedMetButton { (objects) in
        if NeedStore.shared.currentNeed?.committed == true {
            for object in objects {
                NeedStore.shared.needObject?.setObject(true, forKey: "met")
                NeedStore.shared.needObject?.saveInBackground() { (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "You have marked this need as met!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                            (_)in
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToNeedsList", sender: self)
                        })
                        alert.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You cannot declare a need as met if it has not been committed to.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
        } 
    }
}
```

#### 2. Solution

if you want the call `viewNeedMetButton` more generic then add an `onError` closure.

```
func viewNeedMetButton(completion: @escaping([PFObject?]) -> Void,
                          onError: @escaping(Error?) -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Need")
    query.whereKey("committed", equalTo: true)
    query.findObjectsInBackground {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
            completion(objects)
        } else {
            onError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Code that is on the view controller that works with the Parse Call.

```
@IBAction func markAsMet(_ sender: Any) {
    viewNeedMetButton(completion: { (objects) in
        if NeedStore.shared.currentNeed?.committed == true {
            for object in objects {
                NeedStore.shared.needObject?.setObject(true, forKey: "met")
                NeedStore.shared.needObject?.saveInBackground() { (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "You have marked this need as met!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
                            (_)in
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToNeedsList", sender: self)
                        })
                        alert.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You cannot declare a need as met if it has not been committed to.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
        } 
    },
    onError: {
         (error?) in

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                return
            })
    })
}
```